# Corrupted Linux partition after move+resize job, no backup. Any advice?

Tags: partition, corruption, partition-table, move-partition

**TLDR:**
I stupidly corrupted part of my partition table after a move+resize job.
I don't have a backup for the table or the data.
What would you recommend to restore the partition table? I'm ready to put in the work. Ask me whatever information you need.

**What happened:**

My 640 GB HDD (/dev/sda) has Windows 7 and Ubuntu on dual-boot, originally partitioned like this (from what I can remember) :

`[RECOVERY | WIN7-OS | WIN7-DATA | Unallocated ~30 GB | just Linux, no swap ]`

I wanted to resize the Linux '/' single partition (the only one) into the unallocated 30 GB to its left.
I ran a move + resize job with KDE Partition Manager on the '/' partition, from a Linux Live USB key.
During the process the screen froze. I waited between 1 and 2 hours, saw the "HDD" LED on my laptop was off, figured the job was done and rebooted.

Upon reboot, GRUB wouldn't load. I somewhat fixed it with grub-repair and can now boot on Windows apparently (I haven't completed a full boot because I don't want Windows to modify the current state of the HDD. I've mounted and checked the content of the two NTFS partitions from a Live USB and the data looks fine.

However the Linux partition is thoroughly screwed (see this screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/JH2xmQA.png).

I will try to make a full backup of my HDD in the meantime.

**Info on my current partition table:**

I didn't attempt any modification so far, but recorded the outputs of parted, testdisk, sfdisk, and grub-repair.

- NOTE: The concerned drive is **/dev/sda**. /dev/sdb is the Linux Live USB key.
- NOTE: All these outputs were generated after the problem.
- NOTE: my partition table type was detected by `testdisk` as "Intel"
- aberrant screenshot of KDE Partition Manager : https://pasteboard.co/JH2xmQA.png
- result of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` : https://pastebin.com/LG3miXih
- result of `sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda` : https://pastebin.com/KZMswZ01 (Summary pasted at the end of this list)
- display of the `testdisk` quicksearch : https://pastebin.com/njejqbq0
- log generated by `testdisk` : https://pastebin.com/2CPnHf85
- result of the `grub-repair` run : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sfsjPJpvDC/

Quick view of the current partition table (sfdisk output):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 596.18 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Disk model: ST9640423AS     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe0c5913d
 
Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *            63   45062324  45062262  21.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2         45062325  410814179 365751855 174.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        410830302 1250263039 839432738 400.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        410830304 1065938624 655108321 312.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       5360908288 5483792383 122884096  58.6G 83 Linux
```

**Update:**

Well, I tried to make a copy of /dev/sda with CloneZilla and it failed. Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/0LxjtArb

The problem seems to be that the partition table is too messed up for it to work (`Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.`)

I might try again later with `dd`...
Any guess is welcome. Thanks for anyone who tries ;)

Comment: First I would create a copy of the complete /dev/sda into a file on a separate disk (using ddrescue). Then I would try out any repair or recovery attempts with this image.

Comment: Good point, I should mention that in the post. I'm already on it. I planned to use CloneZilla to make an image and a working copy (for preemptive tests) on an external HDD ; I'll check ddrescue too.

Comment: Making an image of /dev/sda is definitely the first thing to do. If you ignore this advice then the next thing to try is to mount **readonly** the /dev/sda5 partition, e.g. `mount -r /dev/sda5 /mnt` and see if the files in /mnt look reasonable.

Comment: Can you edit into the question a guess of how long the "move and resize" took before the hard drive stopped being accessed, so we can get a feeling of how much data was moved. Doesn't need to be accurate, "about 10 minutes" or "about 2 hours" is useful information but obviously accuracy doesn't hurt.

Comment: Added the edit. I don't know exactly when the HDD LED turned off. All I know is I checked it after 1~2 hours and saw it was off...

Comment: @icarus : I tried mounting /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda2 and... blast. I can't mount them ("Device or resource busy"). I actually assumed that they were fine since I can still see these partitions and Windows can still boot, but I never checked if they weren't corrupted as well. Dammit -_-

Comment: "dd" is definitely the tool to use, although ddrescue would not be bad. If you happen to have a disk with a file system that supports copy on write, which pretty much means btrfs, to write the image to then you will save yourself some pain later. If you don't then this stressful time is not the time to start learning btrfs!

Comment: OK. Based on the current partition table /dev/sda3 is an "extended" partition to get around the limit of 4 partitions. /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 should fit inside this but the start of /dev/sda6  sector 5360908288 only makes sense if you have a 2.6TB or bigger disk rather than 640MB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117799/discussion-between-icarus-and-jwav).